# JSF components facets

Tags: jsf

How can I find out which facets are available for a JSF component?
For example: I know that for **the <h:column>** I can use **<f:facet name="header">**, because I have seen it in many examples. 
But let's say I didn't know that **header** facet existed for column. 
How would I find it out? Is there some place where available facets are declared? Or is there a standard place in the documentation where facets are listed?

Comment: Yes the issue is indeed the same, but I don't see a good answer.

Comment: This is for standard JSF components answered in their tag documentation.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

Try autocomplete in your IDE

after the `"` in `<f:facet name="` just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd>

Comment: Well, that depends a lot on the IDE, the real question is "How the IDE knows?"